# aws kms decrypt the ciphertextblob

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, key

a co-worker (who left the company) used the aws kms encrypt --key-id xxxx to encrypt a file ( called ciphertextblob ), I have key-id, and the ciphertext-blob, how can I decrypt the ciphertextblob?

Can I use python boto3 to decrypt it? if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to call the kms boto3 client decrypt method:

```
kms = boto3.client('kms', <region>)
response = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=<ciphertext-blob>)
```

In the response you will have access to the plain text key `response['Plaintext']`

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: I'm confused, how does it know how to decrypt without specifying the key used to encrypt?

Comment: @FergalRooney the CiphertextBlob includes metadata.  When kms encrypt is called, the key info is stored in the metadata.  When you call decrypt it is able to read the key info.

Answer (score 4):

If you have base64 encoded CiphertextBlob

```
import base64
import boto3

kmsclient = boto3.client('kms', region_name=<region>)
decrypted_value = kmsclient.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=base64.b64decode(<ciphertext-blob>))['Plaintext'].decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: The base64.b64decode is very important if you are decrypting the S3 x-amz-meta-rds-tde-pwd meta information of a pvk file.